# The command "sudo apt-get install python-dev, python3-dev" failed and exited with 100 during

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, command-line, pip

It seems like

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

worked just fine but, but it gets error while installing `python-pip`.

[Here's the log of the failed build.](https://travis-ci.org/OrkoHunter/networkx-metis/builds/67582338)

Comment: Try removing the comma after 'python-dev', and just space-separate them. Like this: `sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip`. Does that work?

Comment: Does it fail with the same error? Could you post the error log with the names separated like I mentioned?

Comment: @Alejandro The error log remains the same after removing comma too.

Comment: I just find it hard to believe that the error log would remain exactly the same.. especially since your previous error was because of an invalid package name `python-dev,` which was due to the comma.

Comment: @Alejandro It's building over. Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81048/discussion-between-alejandro-and-himanshu-mishra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error log, the main issue is that `apt-get` is interpreting your attempt to install separate packages with the comma as part of the name of `python-dev`.  To install multiple packages with `apt-get` just separate them with a space.

However, based upon the continued discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81048/discussion-between-alejandro-and-himanshu-mishra) it appears that your travis build was still failing because of other issues you had in your configuration. Certain packages such as `pip` for python3 weren't being named properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading them in separate commands, or remove the comma and just space separate.  Your system thinks you're trying to install a package called "python-dev,"